# Was Theon Greyjoy's final charge unnecessary?

Tags: game-of-thrones

When Theon charges for the Night King in *Game of Thrones* S08E03, I don't know if:

1. Theon knew of Bran and Arya's plan to lure the Night King ("NK").
2. Bran can foresee the failure of Theon's banzai charge and death.

Theon's death appears avoidable. If the NK himself yearned to kill Bran, NK wouldn't have allowed any other White Walker to kill Bran. So Bran didn't need protection from Theon and his soldiers.

Comment: What would you have Theon do? Run from there? And possibly killed from behind. That wasn't Theon anymore. He was brave & defending his home till last breath

Answer (score 7):

**NO**. You have to look at where we are in the story, the dead have all but overrun the castle, a big force including most white walkers made it safely to the godswood. Aside from Theon there is nobody to be seen, most significantly, Jon and Daenarys are not there, just Theon and Bran, of which only Theon is a fighter. This certainly looks like an all hope is lost situation.

So taking a step back, the plan was to lure the Night King to the godswood and throw their strongest warriors at him, this was made clear in episode 2, assuming (correctly) that killing the Night King would end the war. At this point the only thing that Theon can try to accomplish is to kill him, even though it's extremely unlikely he'll succeed. So his last charge is desperate but not unnecessary, if by some chance he'd succeeded they would have been victorious.

Then to come to Bran's 'future seeing', it is a widely-spread believe he can see the future exactly, this is nonsense, just a few things to prove it:

- If he'd known he would have told them "Hey, don't let your Dothraki charge ahead, they'll get slaughtered". Which is one of the main reasons Dany isn't at the godswood. Or he could have told them Dany wouldn't see the signal to lit the trenches, or told them about many other tactical mistakes.
- In Season 7 he seems genuinely surprised that Arya is in Winterfell and not in King's Landing, even after saying he saw her at the crossroads.

From what is shown, Bran reminds more of [Laplace's Demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon), a philosophical construct that says if a demon (intellect) knows the exact state of everything in the past and the present, and has enough intellect to process that data, it can predict the future. Bran does **not** have all past and present knowledge, but he has access to all knowledge and has learned a lot, I also doubt he has a near-infinite intellect. So what is most likely is that any future 'visions' he has are very good guesses, but not anything near really seeing the future.

So no, with the information we have now, it does not seem he knew Arya would kill the Night King just moments later, so this doesn't change a thing to Theon's charge.

Comment: But what about the butterfly effect? Maybe Bran knows but doesn't want to change anything?

Comment: @AnkitSharma while true, it seems like a stretch without real evidence, as we haven't seen that him interfering changes anything or even he himself mentioning that fear. While there are various instances where he seems genuinely surprised by circumstances, another example is him asking Benjen who he is after being rescued, how doesn't he just know?

Comment: OR he has future seeing, and he let everything happen as it did so it had the outcome it did. Maybe it was necessary that the Dothraki get slaughtered so the Night King would be close enough.

Comment: @Luciano but there is no proof for that anywhere in the show, while there are various instances where he seems surprised by an outcome.

Comment: Yep there's no proof, but perhaps he just can't see the whole future, just parts that he looks into. I'm still on the fence if he can see the future or not.

Comment: Bran can "predict" the future by effecting things in the past. Like Hodor

Answer (score 1):

Surrounded by the dead and with no help in sight, death was very likely at that point. So what options did Theon have?

He could have stood his ground and waited for the Night King to come to him, or more likely for his minions to attack. It might delayed things a little, given time for other to arrive.

But there was another opportunity. A clear line to the Night King who didn't seem concerned by Theon, and was in fact willing to let him attack without interference from the other dead who were there. So Theon had a chance, however slim, to kill the Night King then and there, and he took it.

If Bran knew that it wouldn't work he didn't let on. Assuming he did know then it wouldn't have helped to say anything - Theon was going to die, and there is little evidence that Bran can change the future even if he knows it. Or perhaps he knew that Theon's death would be the opening that Arya needed.